# in ionic on registering onHardwareBackButton event the back button still make page to navigate previous page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I am using onHardwareBackButton event of ionic, the event is working correct it is taking me to register function but after going to register function it is still navigating to back page.
I am showing cordova confirm dilogbox on hardwarebackbutton event function so after clicking on cancle he can navigate to back page, but now the popup is also coming and page is also navigating back same time.I have searched and tried many code like

```
e.preventDefault()

e.stopPropagation()
```

both of them are not workign 
I have tried registerBackButtonAction event also but it is not getting deregister when i leave page.
I am stuck with this problem from many hours.
The code which I am using is given below..

```
//this is register event i have used

showalertPopup = function(){
//showing popup
}

$scope.$on '$ionicView.enter', (event, view)->
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction showalertPopup, 100

//like this i am diregistering event
$scope.$on '$ionicView.leave', (event, view)->
    $ionicPlatform.offHardwareBackButton showalertPopup
```

in place of registerBackButtonAction i have used onHardwareBackButton

Comment: Maybe you should try to put a higher priority

Comment: yes i have tried to used that also all the priority like 150,200,300,400,500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is `registerBackButtonAction` with priority 100 (see [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/#registerBackButtonAction)):

> The priorities for the existing back button hooks are as follows:
>   Return to previous view = 100
>   Close side menu = 150
>   Dismiss modal = 200
>   Close action sheet = 300
>   Dismiss popup = 400
>   Dismiss loading overlay = 500

so, basically, you're overriding the **"Return to previous view"** action.
You're going to need a handler to de-register when you're leaving the view:

```
var backbuttonRegistration = null;

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(event, viewData) {
    backbuttonRegistration = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showalertPopup();
        }, 100);
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(event, viewData) {
    if (backbuttonRegistration)
    {
        backbuttonRegistration();
    }
});
```

According to the documentation, `registerBackButtonAction` :

> Returns:  A function that, when called, will deregister this
>   backButtonAction.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
  .controller('homeController', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $ionicPlatform) {

    function showalertPopup() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
        template: 'It might taste good'
      });
      alertPopup.then(function(res) {
        console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
      });
    }

    var backbuttonRegistration = null;

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(event, viewData) {
        backbuttonRegistration = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showalertPopup();
            }, 100);
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(event, viewData) {
        if (backbuttonRegistration)
        {
            backbuttonRegistration();
        }
    });

});
```

PS:

You can `registerBackButtonAction` with the highest priority of all - let's say 1000 - and it will work:

```
    backbuttonRegistration = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showalertPopup();
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: @AniketBhange: Glad I've helped. You can always accept and maybe up-vote my answer. Cheers.

Comment: I still get back to previous view, I tried to set priority to 100 and to 1000 nothing helped me, my action is working but then it get back.